# CodeIgniter Mailing loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, mailing

I would like to ask whether someone has tried to send mails with loop for lets say 1k rows. I would like to make some mailing list and send mails in loop for each email address in table. Or is there any better solution ? THanks

Comment: Dipends on your server timeout and how much mail your host allow you to send. I suggest you to use an external service like http://mailchimp.com/

Answer (score 1):

External (like mailchimp) is the easy and better way to go. But if you would do it yourself, read on.

Create a table called 'mails_to_send', or whatever, with the email address, subject and body as columns (and ID and possible attachments, etc).

Then create a PHP script that loops through x mails, sorted by oldest first (ID ASC), where x is some high number, but not too high so you won't hit PHP execution time limits. Loop through the x records, and send each mail (all necessary info is in the table).

If you want to do this regularly:

Set up a cron job that does this every y (every hour, or every 10 minutes, some number so the amount of emails you need to send is lower than the amount of emails you can send this way). Now forget about it. You can create an admin function to create newsletters, or whatever.